# Python uses "pip install"ed site-packages over default ones in working directory

Tags: python, linux, conda

I accidentally pip installed a package from my local working directory to my main conda environment which I was using before without the problems mentioned below. Now, when I make changes in files, I must pip install it again to be able to use new functions. Reason for that is, that my PyCharm is now calling the module under site-packages instead of the ones in local directory

Another problem is debugging. As I open an original function file from the module in local working directory and set a breakpoint, it is being ignored and I can't debug because of the reason above.

Can I fix this problem, that it uses the module file in my local working directory and my local changes are directly seen by environment?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try pip uninstalling that package from your main conda environment

Comment: Already tried and that causes a ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: Install your package as an editable package (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs)

Comment: "Already tried and that causes a ModuleNotFoundError" => we'd need much more infos to debug this.

Comment: Well, I pip uninstalled the module and tried to run code again and it raised this error. So, now I checked the paths for interpreters and my root directory is actually in the list(where also my module is). But Pycharm still doesn't load my module and says ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'moduledir.class'

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Your first answer has solved the problem, thank you. I would like to mark your comment green, if you want to post it as an answer.